# How to call getFeatureInfo from react-leaflet?

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, maps, openstreetmap, react-leaflet

I have example from github how to add wms layer:
https://github.com/PaulLeCam/react-leaflet/blob/master/example/components/wms-tile-layer.js

but how to getFeatureInfo on click from wms layer?

Answer (score 4):

react-leaflet `WMSTileLayer` component implements core leaflet `L.TileLayer` which [does not support](https://leafletjs.com/examples/wms/wms.html)  `GetFeatureInfo` :

> There’s no GetCapabilities support, no legend support, and no
>   GetFeatureInfo support.

You could consider to utilize WMS plugin for Leaflet which supports `GetFeatureInfo`, for instance  [`leaflet.wms`](https://github.com/heigeo/leaflet.wms)

Installation steps:

install `leaflet.wms` package:

```
npm i leaflet.wms
```

introduce a component for WMS layer:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { withLeaflet, useLeaflet } from "react-leaflet";
import * as WMS from "leaflet.wms";

function CustomWMSLayer(props) {
    const { url, options,layers } = props;
    const ctx = useLeaflet()
    const map = ctx.map;


    // Add WMS source/layers
    const source = WMS.source(
        url,
        options
    );

    for(let name of layers){
        source.getLayer(name).addTo(map)
    }

    return null;
}
```

Result

[image]

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-nr6ukf)

Answer (score 2):

In React-Leaflet V3, the useLeaflet and withLeaflet Hooks are replaced with useMap. The updation to @Vadim Gremyachev code is below.

```
import React from 'react';
import {  useMap } from "react-leaflet";
import * as WMS from "leaflet.wms";

function GetFeatureInfoWms(props) {
    const { url, options,layers } = props;
    const map = useMap()

// Add WMS source/layers
const source = WMS.source(
    url,
    options
);

for(let name of layers){
    source.getLayer(name).addTo(map)
}
return null;
}
```